# Is there a way to flush the first input buffer in successive fgets() functions?

Tags: c

I used the `fgets()` function and used `getchar()` to clear the remaining `'\n'` input buffer.

At this time, a problem occurred, and `getchar()` is often useless because the `'\n'` escape sequence remaining in the input buffer is recorded only when the length of the string received from the user is exceeded.

Using `scanf()` (ex: `scanf(" %s\n", &test);`) as above, there is a method of giving a space before `%s`. Since `scanf()` cannot limit the length of the input string, I couldn't use it because there was a risk of overflow.

How to do it?

```
char student_number[10]
char name[20]
char phone_number[14]

printf("student Number: ");
fgets(student_number, 10, stdin);
getchar();

printf("name: ");
fgets(name, 20, stdin);
getchar();

printf("phone Number: ");
fgets(phone_number, 14, stdin);
getchar();
```

Comment: "Since `scanf()` cannot limit the length of the input string"... You can do that with `scanf("%19[^\n]", name);`  although it does not read the newline, unlike `fgets()`. But it's better not to mix inputs methods. If you are using `fgets()` then use it for *all* the inputs to avoid having to kludge your way around newlines.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've tried that method as well, but the input exceeds the input buffer. I don't know why.

Comment: Well use a bigger buffer than the data field, and throw it away if the string is too long. Or, if the string does not have a newline (so is incomplete), just throw that away, as either the user or your program needs fixing. If someone enters a name that is too long, either they are fooling around or you have not allowed a big enough buffer. But sprinkling `getchar()` into the code is going nowhere. Use a buffer size 1000 bytes. If the string is too long to copy, tell the user.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the advice. As you said, I increased the size of the data buffer enough, and used a macro that takes input with `fgets()` and removes newlines at the end. Thanks to this, we were able to fix it. Thank you very much.

Comment: ... or, in answer to the question, if the input does not contain a newline, then keep calling `fgets` in a loop until it does. Throw away the data, as oversize data is no use anyway.